# Policy on trolling

Tags: discussion

[How to implement artificial intelligence and gravity for enemies in a platformer?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57023/how-to-implement-artificial-intelligence-and-gravity-for-enemies-in-a-platformer)

We've got someone using a famous meme username posting rather clear "meant to cause someone a headache" questions and respected members of the community apparently falling for it.  It's not a huge or disruptive problem so I figure voting to close and/or downvoting should be enough, but there isn't a clear policy I can see on the site here.  Maybe it's better for the community to flag the questions for deletion and the account for suspension.

Some existing Meta posts from other SE sites on the topic I found:

- [How should "humorous" trolling be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36786/how-should-humorous-trolling-be-handled)
- [SOFU definition of "Troll"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18602/sofu-definition-of-troll)
- https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/what-to-do-about-troll-users

What should our policy here be?

Comment: Huh, I didn't feel like I was falling for a troll. Felt like most beginners with strong opinions on things they know nothing about.  :)

Comment: @Byte56: Yeah, I think that's his goal.  Just plausible enough to sound like an inexperienced student but just ridiculous/cocky enough to make you want to smash your head into your desk.  Maybe I'm more prone to beating my head into things than you are, though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest policy is to just judge the questions as they come in. Downvotes and close votes (where appropriate) will suffice. A ban is bound to kick in pretty soon for real trolls. Even more so if the questions come in rapid succession.

If the user is particularly abusive you could flag for moderator attention, perhaps using the "other" option to explain the situation. But I would reserve that for particularly persistent users (those would create new accounts for example, after being banned) and any situation the community really can't handle. Generally they will run out of steam however. Particularly when you don't engage them or egg them on.

So I don't think there is a need for a separate policy, other than "evaluate like you normally would".